# IF-Statment inseide a double for loop?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, if-statement, for-loop

How do i execute an IF statment inside a double for loop, checking if an object in an array equals the selectedItem.label? Here is my try! (didn't work)

```
function klikkA(evt:Event):void{
    for( var j:int = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        for (var k:int = 0; k < 8; k++)
        {
            if (listeA.selectedItem.label != myArray[j][k])
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if(listeA.selectedItem.label == myArray[j][k])
            {
                txtFlagg.text = myArray[j][k];
                break;
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: More detail on what happened when your code "didn't work" may be helpful.

Comment: You actually don't need the top half of the if statement with the continue block. Are you getting errors? Did you try tracing it out?

Answer (score 0):

Since `break` can only jump out of single loop you need to either use flag or goto.

I'd use flag that outer loop(s) check as it generally more accepted practice:

```
var found = false;

for( var j:int = 0; !found && j < 4; j++)
{
    for (var k:int = 0; k < 8; k++)
    {
       .... if(listeA.selectedItem.label == myArray[j][k])
       { ....
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The break statement *alone* will only break the inner loop.

[As you can see in the documentation of break, you can specify a label](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#break)

> break [label]

It explains:

> In nested loops, break only skips the rest of the immediate loop and does not break out of the entire series of nested loops. To break out of an entire series of nested loops, use label

[There's additional documentation on the label keyword](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#label)

It provides an example comparable to yours:

```
outerLoop: for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (var j:int = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if ( (i == 8) && (j == 0)) {
            break outerLoop;
        }
        trace(10 * i + j);
    }
}
/*
1
2
...
79
*/
```